# Count words from keyboard. Not counting repeated

Tags: c++, cin

I'm trying to count the number of words when I write a sentence in the keyboard but repeated words should only be counted once. The sentence must end with a specific string in this case I will use "eof".
For example when I type: "this is a word this word eof" the result should be 4 words.

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string input;
    vector<string> sentence;
    int n=0;

    while (cin >> input && input!="eof")
    {int i=0;
        while (input!= sentence[i] && i<sentence.size())
        {
        i++;
        }
        if (i==sentence.size())
            sentence.push_back(input);

    }
    cout << "\nNumero de palavras: " << sentence.size();

    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles without any errors but when i run it, it shows: "Expression: vector subscript out of range. For information on how your program can cause assertion failure see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts."

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse the order of conditions in the `while` clause:

```
while (i<sentence.size() && input!= sentence[i])
```

That's because, when the array `sentence` is still empty, the first comparison `i<sentence.size()` will fail; and so will the whole clause, without bothering to check for `input!=sentence[i]`, which has no sense when `sentence` is empty.

Comment: Yes that was the problem! Thank you. But now when i enter a sentence for example: "this is a word this word eof" it counts 5 words. Is it counting eof as a word? But if i reverse the condition (cin >> input && input!="eof") it will count only 4 words. Why is that? If the condition input!="eof" is before cin >> input it should not read eof. Am i right?